# Выборка из MySQL итоговых сумм по месяцам

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть поле типа DateTime (дата совершения покупки) и поле со стоимостью заказа. Для построения графика продаж по месяцам необходимо выбрать итоговые суммы по месяцам, отсортировав при этом результаты по дате. Это возможно?

Comment: select month(selldate) m, sum(check) s 
       from yourtable 
       group by m

Comment: Приводите, пожалуйста, в следующий раз вопросе имя таблицы и название полей. Чем больше информации, тем проще отвечать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо из даты получить месяц и сгруппировать по нему данные, чтобы получить сумму (групповая функция `SUM`)

```
select
  DATE_FORMAT(s.sale_date, '%Y-%m-01'), sum(s.cost) 
from sales
group by DATE_FORMAT(s.sale_date, '%Y-%m-01')
```